# Confused about Autoencoder behavior in Keras?

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I trained an autoencoder in Keras and saved the model as two separate models: The encoder and the decoder.

I successfully load these, and then recreate the whole autoencoder with the following:

```
ae_v = decoder(encoder(ae_in))

autoencoder = Model(inputs = ae_in, outputs = ae_v)
```

Now, when I use:

```
autoencoder.predict(sample)
```

The model works properly.

However, I was under the impression that this would be equivalent:

```
a = encoder.predict(sample)

b = decoder.predict(a)
```

However, when doing this, the model produces entirely different results. That is, the end result (b) is different from autoencoder.predict(sample), for the exact same sample. But from what I can tell, shouldn't these be equivalent?

All that's happening is that in the latter code, I'm deliberately taking the output from the encoder and passing it to the decoder, rather than doing one continuous forward pass. I want to be able to do this, so I can make small modifications to the output produced by the encoder before passing it in to the decoder.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Edit: Showing network construction

```
x_2 = Input(shape = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS))
x_3 = Input(shape=(CHOKE_DIM_2, CHOKE_DIM_1))

en_1 = Convolution2D(32, (4, 4,), subsample = (2, 2), activation = 'relu', init = INIT, padding = "same")(x_2)
en_bn_1 = BatchNormalization(momentum = momentum)(en_1)
en_drop_1 = Dropout(dropout)(en_bn_1)

en_2 = Convolution2D(64, (2, 2,), subsample = (2, 2), activation = 'relu', init = INIT, padding = "same")(en_drop_1)
en_bn_2 = BatchNormalization(momentum = momentum)(en_2)
en_drop_2 = Dropout(dropout)(en_bn_2)

en_3 = Convolution2D(64, (2, 2,), activation = 'relu', init = INIT, padding = "same")(en_drop_2)
en_bn_3 = BatchNormalization(momentum = momentum)(en_3)
en_drop_3 = Dropout(dropout)(en_bn_3)
en_flat = Flatten()(en_drop_3)


chokepoint, d_mid, d_out = [], [], []
for i in range(CHOKE_DIM_2):
    a = Dense(CHOKE_DIM_1, init = INIT)(en_flat)
    chokepoint.append(a)
en_out_1 = Concatenate(axis = 1)(chokepoint)
en_out_2 = BatchNormalization(momentum = momentum)(en_out_1)
en_out = Reshape((CHOKE_DIM_2, CHOKE_DIM_1))(en_out_2)    

for i in range(CHOKE_DIM_2):
    x_tmp = Lambda(lambda x : x[:, i, 0:32])(x_3)
    x_tmp.trainable = False
    de_1 = Dense(CHOKE_DIM_1*2, activation = 'relu', init = INIT)(x_tmp)
    de_bn_1 = BatchNormalization(momentum = momentum)(de_1)
    de_drop_1 = Dropout(dropout)(de_bn_1)

    de_2 = Dense(CHOKE_DIM_1*4, activation = 'relu', init = INIT)(de_drop_1)
    de_bn_2 = BatchNormalization(momentum = momentum)(de_2)
    de_drop_2 = Dropout(dropout)(de_bn_2)

    de_3 = Dense(CHOKE_DIM_1*8, activation = 'relu', init = INIT)(de_drop_2)
    de_bn_3 = BatchNormalization(momentum = momentum)(de_3)
    de_drop_3 = Dropout(dropout)(de_bn_2)

    de_4 = Dense(30*40*3, activation = 'relu', init = INIT)(de_drop_3)
    r = Reshape((30, 40, 3))(de_4)
    de_out = UpSampling2D()(r)

    d_mid.extend([x_tmp, de_1, de_bn_1, de_drop_1, de_2, de_bn_2, de_drop_2, de_3, de_bn_3, de_drop_3, de_4, r])
    d_out.append(de_out)
de_true_out = Add()(d_out)

encoder = Model(inputs = x_2, outputs = en_out)
decoder = Model(inputs = x_3, outputs = de_true_out)
encoder.load_weights(LOADPATH + "encoder_weights.h5")
decoder.load_weights(LOADPATH + "decoder_weights.h5")

ae_v = decoder(encoder(x_2))
autoencoder = Model(inputs = x_2, outputs = ae_v)
```

Comment: Where is `ae_in` coming from?

Comment: They don't happen to contain `stateful=True` RNNs, do they?

Comment: ae_in is just an Input layer containing the shape of the input. And no, no RNNs in the autoencoder

Comment: It should be working.... there is a chance the problem is elsewhere in the not shown code. Are you taking this sample from a "generator"?

Comment: no, the sample is just a test picture loaded from a file. Given that the autoencoder is constructed directly from the encoder and decoder, and works properly, I didn't consider other parts of the code.